# get same result in class inheritance

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

what is my wrong ? when i want get result of person class , it give me just secondary person information and do not display their name? am i wrong ? i want set human information by person class and use it any help ?
(**please say me how change kname by human and save change in person class**)
person.h

```
#include<iostream>
#ifndef person_h
#define person_h

using namespace std;

class person {

protected:


  static string kname;

    static int kage;


public:

   static void setnumber( );
   static void setname();

   static void setage();

   void display(); 
};
#endif
```

person.cpp

```
#include"person.h"


string person::kname;
int person::kage =0;



 void person::setage()
{

    cout << " please enter your age \n";

  cin >> kage;


}

 void person::setname()
{
    cout<< "please enter your name \n";
cin >> kname;

}


void person::display()
{
    int i=0;

    for(i=0; i< 3; i++)
        cout << kname <<endl;
}
```

human.h

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include"person.h"
    #ifndef human_h
    #define human_h


    using namespace std;

    class human : public  person {

    protected:

      person k[100];
    static int i;

    static int counter;


    public:

       void info();

};
#endif
```

human.cpp

```
#include"human.h"

int human::number=0;
int human::counter=0;
void human::setnumberofperson(int a)
{
srand(time(0));

    cout << " how many person ? \n";
    cin >> a;
     counter = a;



}

void human::info()
{int i=0;

for (i=0; i< counter; i++){


    k[i].setage();

      k[i].setname();



cout <<  k[i].kname << "\t" << "\t" << k[i].kage << endl;


}
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include"person.h"
#include"human.h"
int main()
{


int a;
person k1;

human e1;
e1.setnumberofperson(a);
e1.sabtename();
k1.display();
}
```

Comment: Please take a minute to make your indentation consistent. It's okay to have your own style, but it's quite jarring to have every other line differently indented

Comment: yes i have a lot of person and want to save their informtions

Comment: Then remove every instance of static in your person class.

Comment: Making a member `static` means that it's value is not associated to any particular instance. Remove all of those `static`s. [Link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static).

Comment: if i clear static i can not save  person value , i want set person value in another class and save changes

Comment: @masterboy I can assure you that you cannot achieve what you want if you insist on using `static`. The first step is to remove `static`. Any problems that this causes are the actual problems you need to solve. Using `static` is only hiding your problem and postponing it to run-time.

Comment: Ouch. My eyes; they hurt!  Please get rid of all those pointless blank lines, settle on a style for where to put spaces and keep your indentation consistent (I recommend [ClangFormat](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html)) - being able to read the code without wanting to carve your eyes out is a must; how do you live with having to read this?

Comment: Just currious; why are your header guards *below* the 'iostream' include? That just seems odd.

Answer (score 1):

this static declarations are the reason of the problem

```
 static string kname;
 static int kage;
```

those variables belong to the class and not to the instances of the class...

so when you do

```
person1.setName("carl")
```

and somewhen after

```
person2.setName("xoce")
```

now both objects have the same name... xoce

the reason why this happens is because static variables dont belong to the object but to the class itself...

## Edit>

to fix that issue, remove the static word and define setter and getters for your class...

Comment: ok please say me how change kname by human and save change in person class

Comment: hi @masterboy I ve updated my answer...